# Add overlay on click, for existing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ratchet

- I have an ultra-basic layout based on Ratchet

  ```
  <div id="view1">

      <header class="bar bar-nav" id="header1">
          <h1 class="title">My Application</h1>
      </header>

      <div class="content" id="content1">

          <nav class="bar bar-tab" id="nav1"> 

               <a class="tab-item active" href="#" id="navitem1">
                  <span class="icon icon-home"></span>
                  <span class="tab-label">Home</span>
               </a>

               <a class="tab-item " href="#" id="navitem2">
                  <span class="icon icon-info"></span>
                  <span class="tab-label">About</span>
               </a>

          </nav>

      </div>

  </div>
  ```
- When the user clicks on an element (fulfilling some criteria, e.g. **has** an `ID` set), an overlay is to be added **covering just this one element** (not a full page one and without messing the layout *at all*)
- If nested element receives the click event, the back-most element is to be picked first and if user clicks again, pick the next child fulfilling the criteria. (Meaning: if the user clicks in the bottom part of the page, the `view1` is picked up first. If he clicks again, it'll be `content1`, then `nav1`, and so on...)

This is mostly an experiment but I still cannot figure it out.

I've tried different solutions (or plugins, e.g. [ContentHover](http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/)) but none has worked.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

The shortest way I could describe the issue is : I want to replicate the way the Inspector (Chrome/Safari) highlights the different elements.

[image: Safari Element Inspector]

---

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pta2mbcv/**

Comment: It's not clear that what do you want.

Comment: @Maysam First off, I want to create an overlay over a clicked element (with an `ID` set). What probably confused you is the issue of stopping event propagation, but that's not some important for now - since I cannot even draw the overlay yet.

Comment: What element? You only have two buttons on your page. What kind of overlay? Fullscreen, or covering the element?

Comment: @Tim All elements with an `ID` attribute set. As for the overlay, I want something covering the *exact* (current) size of the element.

Comment: Can you code up the element (which has to be covered with an overlay) and update your Fiddle?

Comment: @Tim ANY element is to be covered with an overlay. If you clicked on the header (it's an item with an `ID` right?) then the `header` is to be highlighted. And so on...

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `event.target` should do it for you. [View documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

It's not a definite answer, but I've coded something up for you, we can iterate on it. This overlay only appears when the element clicked has an ID.

[JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0epvdca/)

Overlay jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {

  var target = $(event.target);

  if( target.attr('id') ) {
      target.addClass('overlay');
  }

});
```

Overlay CSS

```
.overlay:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(5, 11, 37, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the Update in the original post. ;-)

Comment: Is this closer to what you mean? I find it quite hard to get universally working. I first thought about appending the clicked element in a div with CSS styling, but that would screw up the page is it's more than this. Currently using a pseudo element, but this requires the parent element to have relative positioning. How big is this implementation going to be?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're certainly closer. But there's still a lot of room. This is what I came up with (based on your snippet) : http://jsfiddle.net/eju7hbdq/. It's even closer, its main problem being : if you click the outermost element (e.g. content) then you're done. You'll never have access to the inner elements again. Hmm...

Comment: Nicely done. Would it help if you prevent the overlay from being added if `.content` is clicked, but not for elements inside `.content`? Don't know how yet, but it's not worth trying if this doesn't fix anything. Or is it possible to give the elements that need this functionality a class?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but I've been... struggling as well. I think I'm *very* close to what I originally intended. http://jsfiddle.net/eqe1Lctv/ (JS Only solution).

Comment: Nice, that is actually really close. What is the main problem you're tackling now? I'll continue with this tomorrow, find it rather interesting.